# I am getting the error NoReverseMatch at /blog/view/None/

Tags: python, django

I am makeing a blog with Django. When I try to go to a specific blog post I get this error: `NoReverseMatch at /blog/view/None/ Reverse for 'blog_like' not found. 'blog_like' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` I don't know what is causing this issue at all. Any help would be appreciated

full error:

```
  File "C:\Users\sekoc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\sekoc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\sekoc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\sekoc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\sekoc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 86, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sekoc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'blog_like' not found. 'blog_like' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
[24/Apr/2022 17:30:28] "GET /blog/view/None/ HTTP/1.1" 500 155689
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views import generic
from . import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
# Create your views here.

class create_blog_post(generic.CreateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = models.Blog_Post
    template_name = 'blog_app/creat_post.html'
    fields = ('post_title', 'blog_content')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog_app:all')

class view_blog_post(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Blog_Post
    template_name = 'blog_app/view_post.html'

class delet_blog_post(generic.DeleteView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = models.Blog_Post
    template_name = 'blog_app/delete_post.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user_id = self.request.user.id)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request, 'Post Deleted')
        return super().delete(*args, *kwargs)

class all_blog_posts(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Blog_Post
    template_name = 'blog_app/all_posts.html'

def postLike(request, pk):
    post_id = request.POST.get('blog-id')
    post = Blog.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    ip = get_client_ip(request)
    if not IpModel.objects.filter(ip=ip).exists():
        IpModel.objects.create(ip=ip)
    if post.likes.filter(id=IpModel.objects.get(ip=ip).id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(IpModel.objects.get(ip=ip))
    else:
        post.likes.add(IpModel.objects.get(ip=ip))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[post_id]))
```

view_post.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>{{blog_post.post_title}}</h1>
  <p>{{blog_post.blog_content}}</p>
  <form class="form-inline" action="{% url 'blog_like' pk=blog_post.id %}" method="post">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg like_button" name="blgo_id" value={{post.id}}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>Like</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

> This text was added to ignore "it looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details"

Answer (score 0):

```
action="{% url 'blog_like' pk=blog_post.id %}"
```

Your `urls.py` file does not have a url that is named "blog_like".

Comment: That did not work my URL has a URL named blog_like

Comment: @EthanKoch Update the question to include `urls.py`.